# how to set the size of an array that has already been created?

Tags: java, arrays

```
/**
     * Constructor a matrix which has r rows and c columns.
     * data member nRow and nCol should be set accordingly using setters.
     * AFTER THAT, instance array data should be instantiated to size nRow*nCol
     * @param r: number of rows 
     * @param c: number of columns
     */
    public Matrix(int r, int c)
    {
        setNRow(r);
        setNCol(c);
        data.length = r*c;
    }
```

this is the method i am trying to complete the array data is defined(?) like this:

```
private double[]
```

i am getting an error "The final field array.length cannot be assigned"

If i cant manually set the length of the array to n*r how am i meant to set its size?

Comment: you can't, *The field array.length is final*

Comment: I don't see any assignment... or any field declaration...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not set an arrays size after it has been created. In your code, you don't create an array so you probably want to do

```
data = new double[r*c];
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the size of an array in java. If you mean to reset the size, you can instead use [ArrayList](https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/eGp9FxAW0Tc:APA91bEpVgL8ayDJbInGnJqXLidGQsBssPQCHQ_2ZP_Yx60PZiKs8uvKH2To-7VTFNnhd0T6hreZQsDkWYiwmmwKyYAAOru2nP62MwFdFV_9gpEoAvF9okZmmgYMV8rb4VtLZcOxmc0s/rel/topics/gpsnotifs). Here you can just go on adding elements without worrying about the size of the arraylist being overflown. When you need to get the size, call `size()` function on the arraylist.

Coming to your example, you can just do this:

> ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
>   No need to set the size as in `data.length = r*c;`(Btw, you meant to do `data = new double[r*c];` instead of `data.length = r*c;`)

Answer (score 1):

In java arrays are objects. The length variable of it is a final variable. This means that you can't change the value of it after the array was created. You can use the following syntax to create an array with the size you want:

```
DataType[] name = new DataType[Size];
```

So all you need to do is to put whatever data type you want and r*c instead of Size.